# haskell's "where" in python's list comprehensions

Tags: python

If `lst` is a list of ints, I'd like to have

```
[dif for i in range(1, len(lst)) where dif = lst[i]-lst[i-1] if dif < 5]
```

But apparently, binding a variable like that is not syntactically correct (besides the fact that `where` is borrowed from Haskell).
I can do

```
[dif for i in range(1, len(lst)) for dif in (lst[i]-lst[i-1],) if dif < 5]
```

to make dif run in a length-one iterable. Another option:

```
[lst[i]-lst[i-1] for i in range(1, len(lst)) if lst[i]-lst[i-1] < 5]
```

Also, I can define an intermediate list with differences and then filter it. But neither option is very nice. Is there a good one-liner to have what I want?

Comment: The best one to do in Python is the last code snippet.

Comment: Why a one liner?  Curious...

Comment: @wwii: not that it is really important, but a good one liner is often more understandable than a bigger expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested comprehension with a generator for efficiency:

```
[dif for dif in (lst[i]-lst[i-1] for i in range(1, len(lst))) if dif < 5]
```

Comment: I like this one. It is the intermediate list approach but with efficiency and one-liner-ness (?). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a great 1-liner here.  I suppose that since it is a list, you could use slicing:

```
[a-b for a, b in zip(lst[1:], lst) if a-b < 5]
```

This isn't the *most* efficient since `lst[1:]` creates a copy and `zip` also materializes a new list (on python2.x).  We could do a little better with itertools:

```
from itertools import izip, islice
[a-b for a, b in izip(islice(lst, 1), lst) if a-b < 5]
```

(note that python3.x does away with `izip`, so if you are using python3, just use `zip`).

Comment: You could combine it with a generator expression to calculate `a - b` just once, but I don't see the point here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yep, I thought about that, but that doesn't make for a nice 1-liner.  Then it's a 2-liner (*gasp!*).